# Somando pontos hierarquia

Tags: php, mysql

Meu objetivo é criar um sistema de marketing multi-nivel,
com duas equipes.

Equipe da Esquerda e Equipe da Direita

[image: Como funciona?]

Estou tendo dificuldades para fazer a contagem de pontos.

minha tabela está assim:
  id_user | patrocinador | perna( 0 para esquerda , 1 para direita) | pontos

Lembrando que a rede não possuí limite e que a soma de pontos da esquerda por exemplo inclui todos os pontos dos respectivos downlines.

Preciso de ajuda para fazer essa contagem de pontos.

Answer (score 0):

Para Somar use a função do SQL `SUM()`, mas para utilizar ela você precisa agrupar seus registro com `GROUP BY` passando todos os campos que deseja buscar, não utilize `c.*`, apenas pegue os campos que são realmente necessários para sua aplicação.

**Exemplo:**

```
 SELECT c.id_usaurio,
       c.patrocinador,
       c.perna,
       sum(c.pontos) AS TotalPontos
FROM cic_ciclone_users p
INNER JOIN cic_ciclone_users c ON c.patrocinador = p.id_user
GROUP BY C.id_usuario,
         c.patrocinador,
         c.perna
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Só mais uma pergunta, como eu eu faço para ver os pontos de um determinado usuário.

Comment: Só passar o codigo no sua busca `SELECT  PONTOS FROM cic_ciclone_user WHERE id_user = 1 ` onde 1 é o id que deseja buscar.

Caso a resposta resolveu seu problema, aceite ela no botão ao lado.

Comment: Minha primeira vez no Stack, me desculpe,  por exemplo, o usuário com id_user =1 , ele é patrocinador do 2 e do 3 , o 2 está na perna 0 = esquerda e o 3 na perna 1 = direita. Meu objetivo é calcular a soma de pontos da equipe da esquerda e da direita do usúario... É um pouco complexo admito, espero que entenda, sua ajuda está sendo excelente!

Comment: Não consegui entende, tenta colocar em sua pergunta inicial imagens da estrutura da tabela ou algum script de criação

Comment: veja se ficou um pouco mais claro, estou providenciando imagens da tabela.